# Magento: Category product design update not applied to search result products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm using a design update XML applied to all products under specific categories. The update is applied successfully to those products when browsed to them from those categories, but not when those products are opened from search results. How can I make the design update affect those products when opened from search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a layout handle that you can "grab" for each one of these products and modify the layout through layout xml files.

The key to this process is in the `initProductLayout` method of `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View`. This method is where custom layout handles are added based on the product model. You can grab the layout update object from the controller and call `addHandle()` on it with a string to add that handle. So you'll want to rewrite this method and do something like this:

```
$update = $controller->getLayout()->getUpdate();
foreach ($product->getCategoryIds() as $categoryId) {
    $update->addHandle('PRODUCT_IN_CATEGORY_' . $categoryId);
}
```

Now, in a layout xml file you can target the `<PRODUCT_IN_CATEGORY_##>` handle for the ID of your category(ies) and any layout updates you put here will be applied to the product view page no matter how it is accessed.

Depending on the specifics of your installation, it may make more sense to key the handle with some other category identifier, like the name or URL key, instead of the numeric ID. For this, use `$product->getCategoryCollection()` and iterate through the collection to grab what you need. You may also want to use `$product->getAvailableinCategories()` if you want to include only category IDs that the product belongs to directly (instead of including categories of higher parentage).